# what is the difference between layout and android:layout

Tags: android

i am new to android and would like to know the difference between specifying layout and android:layout .can they be used interchangeably

```
<include layout="@layout/one">
<ViewStub android:layout="@layout/one">
```

As the  include tag uses layout attribute and viewstub tag uses android:layout.kindly specify the difference.

thanks
tejinder

Answer (score 0):

**include ::**

Sharing and reusing layouts is very easy with Android thanks to the  tag, sometimes even too easy and you might end up with user interfaces that contain a large number of views, some of which are rarely used.

For more infor refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html) android developer doc.

**android:layout ::**

Android offers a very special widget called ViewStub, which brings you all the benefits of the  without polluting your user interface with rarely used views.

A ViewStub is a dumb and lightweight view. It has no dimension, it does not draw anything and does not participate in the layout in any way. This means a ViewStub is very cheap to inflate and very cheap to keep in a view hierarchy. A ViewStub can be best described as a lazy include. The layout referenced by a ViewStub is inflated and added to the user interface only when you decide so.

P.S. Kindly Refer [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/category/android/page/2/) Roman Guy's Project which shows how to efficiently use this two layout.

Comment: thanks.i am aware of the difference of include and viewstub .i am referring to the difference between specifiying layout attribute and android:layout attribute.

Comment: Also including the same layout in include and viewstub in the same xml also crashes the app. Cannot we include same layout in include tag and viewstub tag.